# Fabric plugin disappeared from menu bar

Tags: twitter-fabric

Fabric updated to 2.0 two days ago and since then, even with the 2.0.1 update, it disappeared from the menu bar on my mac. I'm running OSX Yosemite.
Anyone know how to bring it back?

Comment: I don't have it either, but if the Fabric is running in the dock, it seems to catch the Archive and offer to Distribute. Version 2.0.1.